# http request: your killing me smalls

Tags: http, logging, log-analysis

I was looking through my Apache Status in WHM and noticed this odd line in the log:

```
POST /your/killing/me/smalls.jpg HTTP/1.1
```

It is mostly from `54.86.11.108` but I have seen at least one other IP.

I've tried to search this, but only turn up a movie catchphrase "You're killing me, Smalls!" that expresses disdain for ineptitude. Am I being hacked or what is going on here?

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of [this question](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/37839/86652). Despite the PUT/GET difference, the accepted answer still applies to this one (I mistapped when flagging though, can't flag again)

Comment: If you are curious enough, you should log the request to record the POST data and http-headers sent by the client.